# Draw into a NSView via mouse event

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouseevent, nsview

i am new to programming, objective-c (and stackoverflow). I'm learning and moving forward very slowly ;) but then I ran into a problem, which google couldn't solve. I have a single window and a NSview and then added a mouse event that should draw the coordinates into my view, but it doesn't. The funny thing is: it is drawn when the mouse moves over the window buttons of my apps window...

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   NSPoint imagePos = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
   NSImage *aImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"mw_bg01.png"];
   [aImage dissolveToPoint:imagePos fraction:1.0];
}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent;{
   mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
   mousePosX = mouseLoc.x;mousePosY = mouseLoc.y;
   NSString* mouseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mousePosX];
   NSPoint textPoint = NSMakePoint(5, 5);
   NSMutableDictionary *textAttrib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [textAttrib setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:10]
               forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
   [textAttrib setObject:[NSColor grayColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
   [mouseString drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:textAttrib];
}
```

I don't know how to go on, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Where is this code? It looks like you've written a mouseDown handler. Depending on where this code is (e.g. in the application versus the view or whatever) it could simply be that where-ever it is happens to be a delegate for the button but not the view.

Comment: It's in the view. I took a mouseDown handler cause i want to test drawing in my view and mousemove didn't get called.

Comment: And: I have no buttons at all, I meant the 3 osx window buttons...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do drawing in the `-mouseDown:` method. Rather, you must do all your drawing in `-drawRect:` (or methods that you call from `-drawRect:`). Try something like this:

```
@interface MyView ()
    @property NSPoint lastMousePoint;
@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)drawLastMousePoint
{
    NSString *mouseString = NSStringFromPoint(self.lastMousePoint);
    NSPoint textPoint = NSMakePoint(5, 5);
    NSMutableDictionary *textAttrib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [textAttrib setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:10]
                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [textAttrib setObject:[NSColor grayColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    [mouseString drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:textAttrib];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
    NSPoint imagePos = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
    NSImage *aImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"mw_bg01.png"];
    [aImage dissolveToPoint:imagePos fraction:1.0];

    [self drawLastMousePoint];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent;
{
    self.lastMousePoint = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

When you get a mouse down event, you simply store the location of the mouse down. The drawing is done in `-drawLastMousePoint` which you call in your `-drawRect:` method. Since you know you need to redraw anytime the mouse is clicked, you call `-setNeedsDisplay:` to inform the view that it needs to be redrawn. Note that the redraw doesn't happen immediately, rather, it will happen the next time through the run loop. In other words, you're saying "hey, something changed, and I need to draw my view's contents again. Please call `-drawRect:` again as soon as possible!"

One other note: `+[NSEvent mouseLocation]` is really designed for getting the current mouse location *outside* the event stream. Typically, in a `-mouseDown:` method, you call `-locationInWindow` on the `NSEvent` passed as the argument to the method. If you need to convert to local/view coordinates, you should call `[self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to learn A LOT ;)
But one thing: when I call setNeedsDisplay it draws mw_bg01.png too, right? This was slow, wasn't it?

Comment: We were all brand new at one point :). Yes, it will draw the PNG again. You shouldn't necessarily worry ahead of time that that will be slow, rather you should test to find out if it's slow enough that it actually makes a difference, and only then spend time changing the way it works. In general, drawing a static PNG to the screen is quite fast. If you do need to improve performance, there are a few options, including: redraw only a portion of the view (see `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`), handle drawing the mouse point in a different view which is a subview of the current one, use CALayers, etc.

Comment: @fw2601 Did this not actually work for you? Why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: It works perfectly and I now try this setNeedsDisplayInRect thing. I dont know how this unaccept thing happened...tried to vote u up, but can't

Comment: @fw2601, OK, good. I just wanted to make sure that you didn't run into a problem implementing it! You won't be able to vote answers up until you have at least 15 reputation points.